# How can I manage swing UI default font sizes without quaqua?

Tags: java, macos, swing, look-and-feel, quaqua

We are trying to get quaqua out of our application. We had been using a call to quaqua to set the font size to be smaller with a call like this:

```
System.setProperty("Quaqua.sizeStyle", "small");
```

Is there an easy to do the same sort of thing without using quaqua? Or does anyone know another good look and feel for OS X?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also had an almost similar challenge, setting all font to a specific font. The code below will change the font size for all ***.font** properties in UIManager to a particular size

```
private static void setFontSize() {
    int fontSize = 12;
    Hashtable defaults = UIManager.getDefaults();
    Enumeration keys = defaults.keys();
    while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
        Object key = keys.nextElement();

        if ((key instanceof String) && (((String) key).endsWith(".font"))) {
            FontUIResource font = (FontUIResource) UIManager.get(key);
            defaults.put (key, new FontUIResource(font.getFontName(), font.getStyle(), fontSize));
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: From a comment on answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8120380/873282 : It easier to use deriveFont(): tree.setFont(tree.getFont().deriveFont(24f));