# Increase size of Text in Jtree

Tags: swing, jtree

I'm trying to increase the size of the text of nodes in my Jtree. Is there any way to do this with/without altering other swing components?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`JTree.setFont`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setFont%28java.awt.Font%29). For example:

```
final Font currentFont = tree.getFont();
final Font bigFont = new Font(currentFont.getName(), currentFont.getStyle(), currentFont.getSize() + 10);
tree.setFont(bigFont);
```

Comment: +1, correct of course - don't forget that you might need to adjust the rowHeight (depending on LAF, win f.i. has it fixed at some value while Metal sizes as needed)

Comment: It easier to use deriveFont():
    tree.setFont(tree.getFont().deriveFont(24f));

Comment: @kleopatra- Assuming that I'm using DefautMutableTree instead of Jtree, how do I change the size then? Checked out DefaultMutableTree's JavaDoc but couldn't find anything.

Comment: @PRamesh there is no such thing as 'DefaultMutableTree' in core api

Comment: Following http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4760081 , the code to adjust the height is as follows:
     FontMetrics metrics = getFontMetrics(getFont());
     setRowHeight(Math.max(getRowHeight(), metrics.getHeight()));